# Why do Higgs phase particles transform nontrivially under the gauge group?

Tags: standard-model, gauge-theory, group-theory, higgs, electroweak

In the electroweak theory, $SU(2)\times U(1)$ is Higgsed down to one of its $U(1)$ subgroups. The resulting theory consists of particles which have $U(1)$ charges.

My understanding of gauge symmetry tells me that if a symmetry is gauged, this $U(1)$ subgroup being one of them, all physical states must be invariant under this symmetry, and hence should not have a $U(1)$ charge in the example above. Where does this understanding go wrong?

Does this have something to do with the difference between the local symmetry and its global version? Do the particles in electroweak theory only have *global* $U(1)$ charge? If this is the case, I would have thought that the local version could render this symmetry trivial?

Comment: So you are also asking why the electron is not gauge invariant?

Comment: That is one way to boil down my question, yes. I've been told that one can make the electron observable by attaching a Wilson line to it which stretches off to infinity. But the resulting operator is gauge invariant, and therefore does not have a charge. Yet, we still see charged particles. I also wonder how this works with the spin 1 particles.

Comment: The spin of the particles has little to do with the construction. You may form Wilson lines w.r.t. all representations, attaching to al spins.

Comment: That makes sense. So, where does the charge arise?

Comment: Whose charge? What does "arise" mean?

Comment: The charge of the electron. I stated that the Wilson line construction results in a gauge invariant operator. What gives this operator charge if it is gauge invariant?

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/388701/66086). Without a charge the coupling to the Wilson line vanishes. Near duplicate.

Comment: The conceit is that the gauge variation is effectively by a mere gauge parameter at infinity, so none:  this is just for fussbudget philosophers. Locally, the electron couples through its charge, or at other distances, through which you compute as though "nothing gives", and it never looks at its bellybutton to question whether it is real or not.